# Asus P8H77-MLE graphics on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, asus

Running Ubuntu 10.04.4 with all the latest updates for the main server. Like to install my on-board motherboard graphics drivers for my asus P8H77-MLE Motherboard.

I currently don't have a graphics card installed, and are not going to. Is there any way to install the on-board graphics drivers for ubuntu 10.04

Under the system > Admin > hardware drivers, nothing is listed.

Is there any web page or terminal I can use to guide me?

Comment: Your board specs say it has your `Integrated Graphics Processor`. That should work out of the box with the your builtin Linux driver. Most of your Intel GPUs work with your open source driver, and I am pretty sure that is your case with your board and your driver.

Comment: Yes, the monitor comes on and works fine, but can't use compiz and can't enable the visual effects under the appearances preferences... I also get grids while moving open windows and open folders, actually moving anything - not folders...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the cause of those problems is the combination of newer hardware with an older Ubuntu release. It would have been fine as a server, but you obviously want to use it as a desktop, otherwise, why have all the desktop components.

I'd suggest, either upgrading to 12.04 (can be done directly from 10.04), or experimenting with backported kernels. For example, to get the latest backported server kernel from Oneric, install the `linux-image-server-lts-backport-oneiric` package, or, for the latest desktop one `linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric`.

Newer kernels should provide better support for newer Intel graphics.

Comment: No, I am using it as a server, so I don't have a problem using it. the default generic driver did everything, so I have not problem working. Thank you for all the help